# Load an HTML page in Chrome in a IE frame

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome

I'm after something like the Chrome frame for IE but the other way around.

As I have one page that needs IE to run proper but all the others run fine and are designed for Chrome. So I was hoping to use some kind of IE frame in Chrome.

This site will be running on a Windows computer.

Comment: As stated, it looks to me like the question probably belongs on SuperUser. It would be topical here *if* you were asking about how to develop code to display an IE window inside of Chrome, but if you're looking for existing code, it's pretty clearly off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IE tab for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd)

Comment: That works but it wont auto close the IE bar when I leave the site. I added the page into the auto include list and added the other sites into the exclude list.